# jProfiler The JVM could not be started

Tags: java, jprofiler

I am newbie to jProfiler. I was install the **`jprofiler_windows_5_1_4_with_jre.exe`** on my windows system. After installation I was try to run the jProfiler on my system it was showing the error message like

**`The JVM could not be started. The main method may have thrown an exception`**

I was installed **`IBM Java1.5`** on my local windows system. **JAVA_HOME** is configured and Java was properly installed.

Anyone plz Guide me how to install **JProfiler** on windows system. Need to add any `environment variables` on my local system to run the JProfiler or not?

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 1):

Do not use JProfiler 5 for anything. It is a very old version. JProfiler 7.1 (the current version can profile Java 1.4 or higher.

Comment: Hi, anyone have idea how to install the JProfiler 7.1 on windows system please let us know. After installation need to add any environment variables or not?

Comment: No, you just run the installer. Then you can start the JProfiler GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Use latest JProfiler version, available [here](http://www.ej-technologies.com/download/jprofiler/files.html)

Please see the installation instructions [here](http://www.ej-technologies.com/download/jprofiler/files.html#installationNotes).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of problem about memory chunk(See below reference for details). If the program has new version, use newer but sometimes programs dont have new version and you have to use it essentially. If any program(not just JProfiler) gives that problem, do below steps:

1. Search for .vmoptions under the program folder.
2. Open it with text editor.
3. Decrease -Xmx size(try decreasing order, for ex: 512m,256m,128m,64m) until finding right size. For each size try to start the program.

[Solution from Jetbrains](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1185)